# Displaying an image at the center of the screen at a height of 77px;

Tags: html, css

I have designed a webpage .The top part is header with `height:77px` .After header i want to add a image at the center of the  screen with width of `width: 960px;` .Now the problem that i am facing is that the image is coming from the top inside of the header means that second image is coming from the top whereas i need to display after the height of 77px;

Here is the HTML..

```
 <div id="headerbodyimage" style="width: 960px; margin-top: 77px;  margin: 0 auto;" class="headerbody-wrapper">

 </div>
```

And here is the CSS..

```
.headerbody-wrapper {
background: url("../images/banner.jpg");
height: 242px;
position: inherit;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }
```

I have tried to change `position` but its collapsing whole page

Here is my header code in html..

```
 <div class="header-wrapper">
 </div>
```

and this my CSS.

```
.header-wrapper {
background: url("../images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
float: left;
height: 77px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }
```

Please help me.

Comment: margin-top: 77px;  margin: 0 auto;? you are overwriting margin top property. try margin:77px auto 0px auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `margin: 0 auto;` in your `style` attribute you overwrite your `margin-top: 77px;`. `margin: 0 auto;` is the shorthand for `margin-top: 0; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto;`. Go with:

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4svMy/1/)**.

HTML:

```
<div class="header-wrapper"></div>
<div id="headerbodyimage" class="headerbody-wrapper"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-wrapper {    
    z-index: 60001;     
    width: 100%;
    height: 77px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/77x77") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.headerbody-wrapper {    
    z-index: 60001; 
    background: url("http://placehold.it/960x242");
    width: 960px;
    height: 242px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but its making the top header down with 77px and header body image is 77px inside to the top header image

Comment: i have updated my post with header code ..Please see and help me

Comment: @user3699193 Is the `<div id="headerbodyimage" ... >` inside or underneath the `<div class="header-wrapper">`?

Comment: its underneath of <div class="header-wrapper">

Comment: Why is this problem coming sir?

Comment: @user3699193 I updated the code in the answer and the demo. I think that should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
headerbody-wrapper {
    background: url("../images/banner.jpg");
    height: 242px;
   position: inherit;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 60001; 
  background-positon:xxx;
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position